Does This Concatenation of PDFs Really Produce a Seam?
This question is in reference to the post: On Adding a Colorized One-Sided Margin to a Tikzpicture
While out for a walk today, a pedestrian approach (no pun intended) to solving the question posed therein occurred to me:
First, run the code posted in the MWE with \usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,right=0in,paperwidth=4.00in,paperheight=2.15in]{geometry} substituted in; that is, run---
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,right=0in,paperwidth=4.00in,paperheight=2.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament, tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.6cm]
    \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
    \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=2cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
    \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=2cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
    \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=2cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mytext, color=transparent!0]
    \node (n) at (current page text area) {\scalebox{1.00}{Everything is not fine!}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \fill[gold] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which produces

Call this, Output1.
Secondly, create a 0.25in v 2.15in plain gold rectangle, with say, the code
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=0.25in,paperheight=2.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\pagecolor{gold}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \par \emph{ }
\end{document}

which produces

Call this Output2.
Finally, concatenate Output1 and Output2 as follows:
\documentclass[12pt,border=0pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \includegraphics{Output1}\includegraphics{Output2}
\end{document}

which gives the following:

But alas, is there a seam there? I ask, because if I zoom out a little, it seems to disappear:

On the other hand, if I continue to zoom in, the seam appears to be ever present.
QUESTION: Is a seam really produced by my concatenation? If so, how may I correct it?
I compile with XeLaTeX.
Thank you.

all non-integer calculations are approximations. that includes calculating positions. so that might cause a slight discrepancy. the easiest solution is to produce the graphic as a single picture (either inside the main document or outside for inclusion doesn't matter). alternatively, make the second rectangle slightly wider than require and overlap the images when including. (1pt is generally sufficient to offset the inaccuracies unless they've really accumulated, which shouldn't be the case here.)
